# anaconda cannot find pip3 and do not want to use pip or pip2

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, pip, anaconda

I have pip installed in my anaconda3 folder, but pip3 is installed in another folder in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (not in anaconda folder which is in my home folder).

How I do install pip3 for anaconda so I can use pip3 to install djangorestframework in my virtual environment? I cannot use the pip3 in the /usr/lib/ folder because I would need to sudo, I do not want to use sudo.

Comment: create new environment using conda with python 3, refer to this: https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html

Comment: I guess this will do: `conda create --name <env_name> python=3`

Comment: you need to activate your environment and after that use conda to install any package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Using this:

```
conda create --name <env_name> python=3
```

It will create a new virtual environment using python 3 for conda. You may install your packages using `conda install <package_name>` after activating your environment.

Refer [here](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html) for more on conda environments.

Comment: are you saying i shouldn't use pip3?

Answer (score -1):

First create an environment with conda then activate it:

```
 conda create -n py3k python=3.4 
 source activate py3k
```

If you have a Python3 environment as your default, then `pip` works out-of-the-box without needing to remember to do `pip3`